# php apply rules from inside one table to other tables

Tags: php, mysql

i don't know how to explain it so i will show you what i am trying to do.

mysql tables

Table Rules:

```
id|   name|maker|model |type|price_rule
1 |client1|bmw  |x5    |    |24
2 |client2|     |      |2.0 |13
```

Table Products_client1:

```
id|maker|model |type|price
1 |bmw  |x5    |2.4 |10
2 |opel |vectra|1.6 |5
3 |ford |mondeo|2.0 |15
```

now, i have a list of over 500k products in my mysql db, and need to update the price in the products table, with the rules from the rules table :

```
UPDATE products_client1,client2,... SET price=price+price_rule WHERE maker=maker or model=model or type=type
```

the thing is that not all clients in the Rule table have maker and model and type, some have only maker or only model or only type or a combination of the 3 and every client has a separate products table.

products_client1, products_client2.....

```
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM Table_rule";
        $Res = $conn->query ($sql) or die ("Error : " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error);
        While($Row = $Res->fetch_assoc ()) { if (isset ($Row ["id"])) { $c_id[] = $Row ["id"]; if (isset ($Row ["name"])) { $c_name [] = $Row ["name"]; if (isset ($Row ["price_rule"])) { $c_price [] = $Row ["price_rule"]; }
    
    $c_id_count = count($c_id);
    
    For ($x=0; $x <> $c_id_count; $x++) { $sql_updt = "UPDATE Products_" . $c_name [$x] . " SET price=price+" . $c_price [$x] . " WHERE "; 
$Conn->query ($sql_updt); }
```

Where what ? If this is  = to this do this.....how to i check if every rule has 1...2....3....4...n maches or just 1 and hot do i apply price edit only to that item....there is always a match or more

Comment: When does a rule match a product: when they have the same maker? Model? Type? Any of those? All of those?

Comment: maker, model, type....1, 2 or all 3

Comment: `every client has a separate products table`, that is a problem. You're going to have to dynamically build up table names in your queries. Perhaps you need to rethink the overall design. We can help if you give us enough information about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: i need to update the products table with client1 rules > export to csv; update client2 rules > export to csv and so on. I did it with every client its own table thinking it might be easyer.

Comment: I don't understand how clients are matched to rules. Can you please edit your question with more sample data and show which ones should and shouldn't match.